# How To Add,Delete,Update,Retrieve Appointment(Task) Data From Wunderlist and iOS Calender in UWP

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

hello friends I want to develop an application in which user can add,Update,Delete,retrieve Appointment Task from Wunderlist and iOS Calender. Do you have any idea how to implement this in UWP(Desktop Application)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do you have any idea how to implement this in UWP(Desktop Application) Thanks in advance.

For your requirement, you could refer [**Manage appointments**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/contacts-and-calendar/managing-appointments) UWP official document that

> Through the [`Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments`](https://learn.microsoft.com/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments) namespace, you can create and manage appointments in a user's calendar app. Here, we'll show you how to create an appointment, add it to a calendar app, replace it in the calendar app, and remove it from the calendar app. We'll also show how to display a time span for a calendar app and create an appointment-recurrence object.

And we also [code project](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Appointments) that you could refer directly.

Comment: thanks for your valuable reply yes i refereed this  appointment sample project its create a task or appointment in local machine calendar but i want create a task in Wunderlist and iOS calendar.

Comment: do you have any idea.. how to create a task to wunderlist ? :(

Comment: Do you mean that you want to create task to wunderlist  within uwp app?

Comment: do you have any idea how to register my uwp sample  app to this [link](https://developer.wunderlist.com/apps)  where and how to get the **APP URL** and **AUTH CALLBACK URL**   :(

Comment: The better way is make a service to store appointment that comes from uwp client and sync to ios  calendar for same account.

Comment: Currently we have not provide such service, you need create the  service base on your requirement.

Comment: Zhu - simply i want to add appointment to user calendar by gmail account. how to achive this in uwp app  ?